# Is it possible to have only certain columns striped in a b-table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a basic b-table with row striping enabled:

```
            <b-table :fields="myfields" :items="myData" striped>                 
            </b-table>
```

Is there a way to only have some columns of the table striped (instead of all) ?
If there is no easy way, would there be some feasible workarounds to achieve the same (or similar) affect ?

EDIT: I was able to get a bit closer to what I want, by removing "striped" from b-table, and using _cellVariants, like this:

```
myData: 
[
               { col1: 1,  col2: 'A row1', col3: 'B row 1',  _cellVariants: { col2: 'secondary',  col3: 'secondary' }  },
               { col1: 2,  col2: 'A row 2', col3: 'B row 2' },
]
```

Note that the data in my table is fixed (will be hard coded in the array).
This displays columns: col2 and col3 with a dark grey background, for  the 1st data row. This simulates the striping effect that I wanted.

Is there a way to display it in the same background color that is used, when "striped" is specified in b-table ? The striped color seems to be a lighter grey.

Comment: assuming b-table is bootstrap, what version?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap v4.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in feature from bootstrap vue b-table to achieve what you want.

But you can use CSS as a workaround, something like this:

```js
  <b-table :fields="myfields" :items="myData">
    <template #cell(column)="data">
      <td :class="{ 'striped-column': data.column.field === 'columnName' }">
        {{ data.value }}
      </td>
    </template>
  </b-table>
```

```css
.striped-column {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: this did indeed change the background color - but in my case, the color only changed for part of a cell, not the whole cell.  Also, the rows of the table became taller than with my original code. So it did not suit 100% in my case, but thanks anyway.